# Laravel4.2 - Share customise function on Models

Tags: php, laravel-4, model

I have 2 Models ( tables ) on my Laravel4.2 Web Application

Which is : **_blog** & **_text**

I'm still learning the process of managing data & logic between Controllers & Models with Laravel

On a my **Blog Models**, I got a function call **listBlog** , which is pass a parameter to have a dynamic querying for the **_blog** table.

But when comes to **Text Models**, do I need duplicate the **listBlog** function again to **listText** ?

It seems repeative for me & what if I got more than 5 tables that wanted to share the function ?

Below are my example codes for **Blog Models** also **Text Models** :

**Blog :**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Blog extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = '_blog';
    public $timestamp = false;

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public static function listBlog($nextID=0,$status='approved')
    {
        $query = Blog::where('status',$status);
        $query = $query->orderBy('id','desc')->skip($nextID)->take(6);
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

**Text :**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Text extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = '_text';
    public $timestamp = false;

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public static function listText($nextID=0,$status='approved')
    {
        $query = Text::where('status',$status);
        $query = $query->orderBy('id','desc')->skip($nextID)->take(6);
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

Because on Laravel Framework, I need create a new Model .php file **Blog.php** & **Text.php** to call eloquent method on controller eg : **Blog::all();** or **Text::listText(0,'rejected');**

is there any way to share a global function or method like **listData** instead of **listBlog** or **listText** and not to copy and paste multiple time on Models.php? function on Laravel's Models file?